# doGet failed on google addon script file

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trace

I am trying to trace email status with using inline image in an email.

For getting response i am using following code.

```
// handles the get request to the server
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter); 
  var method = e.parameter['method'];
  switch (method) {
    case 'track':
      var email = e.parameter['email'];
      updateEmailStatus(email);
    default:
      break;
  }
}


    function updateEmailStatus(emailToTrack) {
  
  // get the active spreadsheet and data in it
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // get headers
  var headers = data[0];
  var emailOpened = headers.indexOf('status') + 1;
  
  // declare the variable for the correct row number
  var currentRow = 2;
  
  // iterate through the data, starting at index 1
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[0];
    
    if (emailToTrack === email) {      
      // update the value in sheet
      sheet.getRange(currentRow, emailOpened).setValue('opened');
      break;
    }
    currentRow++;
  }
}
```

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10f--FRKZ3d8qiYF71TmAroSn_vpTjDMSYZA_Wls5CDI/edit?usp=sharing)

it works in a stand alone file but not working in a addon script project. Is there any way to trace out the send email using apps script ?
Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. I have change the code little bit and create a new draft as more than one inline image was added to the existing draft.

The change is here

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Email_Status');
```

After this few changes i deployed as new webapp and it started working. Thank you for contribution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); remove this
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);//change this by hardcoding the id
```